# Access controller from a directive within a directive that has isolated scope

Tags: javascript, controller, angularjs, directive

I'm just starting out with angularJS, and I've having a bit of an issue getting my head around scoping with directives and controllers.

In the example I've linked to below, I have a set of two directives; one attribute directive (`showMessage`) and one element directive (`parentDirective`).

http://jsfiddle.net/ejSxM/1/

I'd like to use `showMessage` as a behaviour, so that when an element is clicked, it fires a function in the controller. This works fine on normal html elements, but when I apply it to my `parentDirective`, `showMessage` takes the scope of the `parentDirective`, and not the controller.

This can be demonstrated in the attached example. When clicking on "I'm by myself", the directive has the scope of the controller, so the `showMessage` function in the controller scope calls fine. When Clicking on "I'm a directive" however, the directive now has the scope of the parent directive, and flags an error.

Is there a way that I can access the controller scope from the nested directive, even when the parent directive has an isolated scope?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass in expressions to your directive like this:
`<my-directive onsomeevent="functionInMyController()"></my-directive>`

And then in your directive:

```
...
scope: {
    onevent: '&onsomeevent'
},
link: function() {
    element.bind('click',function () {
       scope.onevent(); 
    });
}
...
```

That is, you bind the expression from the `onsomeevent` argument so that you can execute it inside your directive without knowing what the expression is. The expression is executed on the parent scope, so `functionInMyController` needs to be defined in the parent scope. You can also pass in variables from your linking function to that expression which you can find an example of here (in the scope section) [directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Comment: Thanks for your help. This different approach fits my needs perfectly, and I can do away with the now unnecessary behaviour directives. If anyone is interested, here is another jsfiddle using the above approach: http://jsfiddle.net/HDEF7/3/

Answer (score 1):

You can set a controller for a directive.

```
controller - Controller constructor function. The controller is instantiated 
before the pre-linking phase and it is shared with other directives if they 
request it by name (see require attribute).
This allows the directives to communicate with each other and augment each other's 
behavior. The controller is injectable with the following locals:
$scope - Current scope associated with the element
$element - Current element
$attrs - Current attributes obeject for the element
$transclude - A transclude linking function pre-bound to the correct transclusion
scope:     
function(cloneLinkingFn).
```

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive